# Effect of adding new columns to existing table

Tags: oracle

In my project there is new requirement, in which I've to add two new columns to the existing table.

How I can analysis the effect of adding two new columns to this table?

Please note:
I already find all dependencies using all_dependencies view and also I have used all_source to find few more information.

Could you please guide me what will be the right approach to follow in this project?

Edit1: As this question attracted the negative points. I would like to improve according to your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a column will not impact view/triggers/procedures, if the developers have used proper column names in them. But if someone used `select * from your_table` in any of the view/procedure/triggers, then you might be in trouble.

You are already on right path. Just check `dba_source` properly. Say your table name is `schema1.table1`, the do a search in `all_source` using `where upper(text) like '%TABLE1%'`

Also if there are `dblink` in other databases to your database, then you might need to take care of that too.

Comment: For a view this will **not** matter. A `select *` inside a  `create view` will be expanded to the list of columns valid at the time the view was created. The `*` will **not** be stored in the view definition

Comment: Thanks for the solution.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Agree to that. But if same view is used in proc/trigger as `insert into xyz(col1,col2) select * from view` then that particular proc/trigger might fail. So it is better to resolve it at `view` level.